# Show response in the div tag

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm calling a method by AJAX and I'm actually receiving a response, but I want to print that answer or show it in a `div` and I'm not doing that correctly.I want my response to be shown in a div `#result`

```
<div id="result"></div>
<input type="button" name="name" value="try" onclick="DepListQuery()" />

<script>
    function DepListQuery() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetData","Home")',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {

                alert(response);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert("something get wrong u.u");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Here is my method

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetData()
{   
    var st = "kyo please help me u.u";
    return Content(st);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to change your `GetData` method to [return `Json`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult(v=vs.118).aspx):

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetData()
{
    var st = "kyo please help me u.u";
    return Json(new { success = true, message = st }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And then you can show the response in your `div` tag like this:

```
success: function (response) {
    $('#result').text(response.message);
},
```