# Getting empty array while ajax query to MVC controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using `$.ajax` method to get the data from the MVC controller. I am using`POST` method according to the [JSON Hijacking](https://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx/) for security standards. If I debug I am able to get the data in controller, but after returning data to the $.ajax's success function then it is showing me empty json array like below.
[image]

In controller I am using method as below:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetUsersFromOrganization(string searchString) {
            string accessToken = await SampleAuthProvider.Instance.GetUserAccessTokenAsync();
            var result = await graphService.GetUsersFromOrg(accessToken, searchString);
            var json = JObject.Parse(result);
            var valueJSON = json.GetValue("value");
            return Json(valueJSON, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);               
        }
```

`json` contains below data:
[image]
Here is the `valueJSON` value
[image]

Comment: In your C# code, what is `valueJSON`?

Comment: Change your code like this. It may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/46532175/2946329

Comment: @MarkC. it is having JSON response

Comment: That doesn't help.

Comment: @S.Akbari.. even if I tried that, same issue

Comment: @MarkC. I have updated code and screenshot

Comment: What is the value of `valueJSON`? I don't need to see what `json` object is

Comment: Value of `valueJSON` is, you are seeing a parent element in screenshot right. That is the one.

Comment: ok, and after you run `var valueJSON = json.GetValue("value");`, what is in `valueJSON`? That's the real question. Just because we can see the parent object doesn't prove anything.

Comment: Added valueJSON screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The valueJSON is a `JToken`, `Json(valueJSON)` method is serializing your valueJson as a `JToken` class and not as the deserialized array of objects that you need, you can try to return the `JToken` as a string with `return Content(valueJSON .ToString(),"application/json");` or parse the `JToken` to the original array of objects.

Comment: You are right! If I modify code as you said `valueJSON.ToString()` then in success method of ajax it is giving me values. Thank you